How do I convey to the hiring committee that I want to be a good academic mentor?
I'm applying for a junior professorship position at a STEM department in the EU. I know that this department values collegiality and providing good-quality mentorship to graduate students and postdocs and that's one of the main reasons why I'm applying there. Over the last couple of years I've spent a lot of time thinking what kind of research advisor I'd like to be. I've learned many lessons by example from great mentors I had and by counter example from a lot of horror stories (some of which I've witnessed myself, some coming from this SE). I've decided to make it a mission for myself to be a caring, present, and supportive advisor to my future students.
The thing is, thus far I haven't supervised anyone throughout the full Ph.D. I've briefly mentored master students here and there during my Ph.D. and now during my postdoc I'm co-supervising a Ph.D. student who just started 3 months ago. While I already started applying my mentoring style with that student, I think it's still too early to show that "it works". How do I convey to the hiring committee that I will be a caring advisor if I don't really have data to back up my claim? I want to bring this up in my application and if I get there, at the interview. But anyone can say that they plan to be a great advisor. All I really have to back up my statement is that I've been taking notes for myself on being a good mentor, I've given it a lot of thought over the years, and I have my role models. I can also describe some items I implemented with the current Ph.D. student. I feel I have to be delicate to not make it sound fake/forced and also not make it sound negative like "I don't want to be like all those nasty toxic advisors out there!"...
What's my best shot at convincing the hiring committee that I want to be a caring mentor?

Sounds like your heart is in it. Is there evidence you can bring to the table?

How do you know that you're good? Just to be a bit self-critical, motivation is the first step, but this doesn't mean that you're actually good, does it? Not implying the opposite, but let's just be honest ;)

I would make sure to:
(1) Not focus on it, except where appropriate (e.g., a brief mention in a cover letter, or as part of a teaching statement).
(2) Have specific and concrete ideas for how you would manage students. Don't say "I would prioritize being a good mentor," but instead say "to effectively mentor my students I would do X, Y, and Z" and explain your reasoning. This provides evidence that you value mentorship because it shows you have thought carefully about it.
(3) Mention that you are attracted to the department because you think it values high-quality mentorship.

Other than saying you aspire to be a good mentor, but have had, as yet, few opportunities to practice it, I think there is little you can say yourself that will be convincing. There is no evidence that you can point to in such situations and a recommendation letter from a former mentee probably isn't a good choice.
You can also say that the reason you are applying to this particular institution is the importance they place on such relationships and that you hope to both learn and contribute.
But if you can have one of your letter writers, a professor, perhaps, say such things they will carry some weight. It would need to be someone who knows it is true, of course.
But much of what you might say will possibly sound obsequious, as if you are just checking boxes and saying what you think you should say. Think hard about what you might say and avoid such things.
As a side note, I'd also suggest being a bit humble about your style and theories of mentorship. Not just in what you say, but in how you think about it. You may have more to learn than you think.

Consider completing training about mentorship.
It is great that you want to be a good mentor for students, but this does not always come naturally, very often Professors do not have training on mentoring or supervision of Master/PhD students.
You can make a difference if you obtain explicit training on good supervision practices for Master and PhD students, particularly about PhD students, as there are many aspects that can go wrong during a supervisory relationship (culture, research, expectations, etc) and it is much better to get experience on these issues ahead of supervising a student.
As an example, the University of Groningen has developed a qualification about supervising PhD students. You can probably find something similar (short course, workshop) in your local community or online.
Disclaimer: I work at the University of Groningen and I have completed this qualification. It did help obtain an overview of the PhD process and possible issues.

Thank you for suggesting that, that sounds like a useful thing to do and not just for my application but for the benefit of my mentoring in general.

Depending on the University, you will potentially have a teaching philosophy statement (or for some, a teaching and mentoring philosophy). You can include it there. If there is not such a document, you can place it in the cover letter (in brief).
Unfortunately, however, while I laud your commitment to mentorship, it is frankly not that important at this stage for you. The presumption is that everyone should aim to be a good mentor, and that all incoming junior faculty have that intention. When it comes time for tenure/promotion, then your success as a mentor will be critically evaluated.
Your main focus should be a very strong research program proposal, backed up by a strong CV, and letters of support. That is what will get you an interview. When you interview, you will have many opportunities for open discussion, and there you can convey that you have not only thought about a research project/area, but also on how to ensure and promote student success.

You don't specify what career stage you're in, but I assume early stage? If so, the hiring committee will understand that you haven't had time to accumulate much mentoring experience, so don't feel insecure about this. If ideas are all you have, then phrase those persuasively.
To stand out against other applicants and interviewees, I suggest that you develop one or more of the following items:

A mentorship section of one or two paragraphs in your teaching and/or research statement.

One paragraph about mentorship for your cover letter.

If you're allowed to submit additional unrequired documents with your application, you could write a full-page mentoring statement, which you will also read and practice as preparation for your interview.

A concrete plan for a mentoring program, about one page, nicely formatted and possibly illustrated, that you can hand out at your interview. You will be the only applicant to submit such a plan!


You can include things like these in your mentoring statement:

How mentorship helped you in your academic growth; some examples.

Why mentorship is important for students, the institution, and your field.

Purposes of mentoring: expose students to the research process, scientific methods, instruments, preparing a paper for publication or a conference; increase equality for students from weaker academic backgrounds; encourage problem solving and creative thinking in scientific research; increase diversity and inclusion in your field…

Types of students who can benefit from mentoring: probably all, but you could mention young women and people of color in STEM fields.

Specific mentoring modes you envision. Emphasize including students in your own research, or supporting their research. Also: discussing possible career paths, supporting mentees with writing grant applications... What else do you have in mind?

Qualities of a great mentor, besides the caring that you mention.

Qualities, skills, and knowledge you want to help your mentees develop. Example: understanding the importance of failure in scientific studies.


I have the impression that you will be a great mentor! Present yourself confidently and show your enthusiasm for mentoring. There is no reward for humility in job applications or interviews. The hiring committee wants to know what creative new ideas you can bring to the department. Your ideas and enthusiasm may be as valuable as someone else's perfunctory and forced advisory experience.

Consider creating a teaching portfolio
It might be useful for you to construct a teaching portfolio and include material on your philosophy and practice for teaching and mentoring in this document.  A teaching portfolio is a useful resource to keep track of your teaching experience, but it can also include more high-level things like your aspirations, philosophy, approach, likes, dislikes, fears, etc.
Since you are early in your career, you are correct that you may lack evidence of much accomplishment/success in mentoring, but you can at least convey your thinking and approach on this topic.  Your teaching portfolio can convey your aspirations with regard to mentoring and it can also set out your thinking about how to accomplish your aspirations.  If you have had previous experiences with "toxic" approaches to mentoring then you might also include some material explaining the things you have observed that are bad practice and that you wish to avoid.
If I were you, I would construct a high-quality teaching portfolio that is an appropriate document to show to institutions where you are applying for positions.  You can offer to give this to the panel to show your philosophy, approach and experience in this area.  This would allow you to rely on written material and then you can speak lightly about this in the interview without sounding forced.  Your teaching portfolio is something you can build on over your career, both to keep track of the courses ou have taught and to build on your general philosophy and approach.
